# Clear string from spaces powerbuilder

Tags: string, powerbuilder

I have string

```
'TEST1, TEST2, TEST3'
```

I want to have

```
'TEST1,TEST2,TEST3'
```

Is in powerbuilder is a function like replace, substr or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use the database since you probably have an active connection.

```
string ls_stringwithspaces = "String String String     String"
string ls_stringwithnospace = ""
string ls_sql = "SELECT  replace('" + ls_stringwithspaces + "', ' ', '')"

DECLARE db DYNAMIC CURSOR FOR SQLSA;
PREPARE SQLSA FROM :ls_sql USING SQLCA;

OPEN DYNAMIC db;
IF SQLCA.SQLCode > 0 THEN
       // erro handling
END IF
FETCH  db INTO :ls_stringwithnospace;
CLOSE db;

MessageBox("", ls_stringwithnospace)
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure there is (you could have easily found it in the help) but it is not quite helpful, though.

Its prototype is `Replace ( string1, start, n, string2 )`, so you need to know the position of the string to replace before calling it.

There is a common wrapper for this that consists of looping on `pos()` / `replace()` until there is nothing left to replace. The following is the source code of a global function:

```
global type replaceall from function_object
end type

forward prototypes
global function string replaceall (string as_source, string as_pattern, string as_replace)
end prototypes

global function string replaceall (string as_source, string as_pattern, string as_replace);//replace all occurences of as_pattern in as_source by as_replace 

string ls_target
long i, j

ls_target=""
i = 1
j = 1
do
    i = pos( as_source, as_pattern, j )
    if i>0 then
        ls_target += mid( as_source, j, i - j )
        ls_target += as_replace
        j = i + len( as_pattern )
    else
        ls_target += mid( as_source, j )
    end if
loop while i>0

return ls_target

end function
```

Beware that string functions (searching & concatenating) in PB are not that efficient, and an alternative solution could be to use the `FastReplaceall()` global function provided by the [PbniRegex](http://sebastien.kirche.free.fr/powerbuilder/en.html#pbni) extension. It is a c++ compiled plugin for PB classic from versions 9 to 12.

Answer (score 0):

I do that:

```
  long space, ll_a
     FOR ll_a = 1 to len(ls_string)
            space = pos(ls_string, " ")
            IF space > 0 THEN
            ls_string= Replace(ls_string, space, 1, "")
            END IF
     NEXT
```

Comment: So, if your source string does not contain any space, you still loop `len(ls_string)` times on the string, calling `pos()` each time? Urgl!